# meteor moment TypeError: n is undefined

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm using this package : 
https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment

The timezone function , moment.tz() , throws error "TypeError: n is undefined".

The function throws the error for most inputs, including basic examples from the moment timezone documentation website : http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

e.g. :

moment.tz("2013-12-01", "America/Los_Angeles").format();   will throw the error.

Comment: `n`? There is no `n` in the code you have posted…

Comment: Have you tried adding a moment timezone package? that functionality is usually separate from core Moment

Comment: @royhowie `n` can actually be a variable in the minified code. It may be the tz package isn't in as stubailo suggusts

Comment: @Akshat you're right. Didn't even think of that.

Comment: @stubailo - yes, have the moment-timezone package installed.  I'm using the framework Meteor, so this is their wrapper package for moment-timezone :  https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was already another version of moment timezone already being included in the project in the 
/lib
folder.
I removed the old /lib version.

The Meteor packaged version https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment works fine.